# Matlab structure to MySql database

Tags: mysql, database, matlab, structure

I have a structure in Matlab. The structure contain 2.1 million rows with a mixture of Double, Integers and Char. The structure is called TaqQ;

```
TaqQ.time 2100000x1 uint32,
TaqQ.bid 2100000x1 double,
TaqQ.ex 2100000x4 char,
```

How can i in a fast, way transfere that structure to MySql?

Maybe by save the structure to an csv file and then import it to mysql. I tried that:

```
csvwrite('test.csv',[TaqQ.time TaqQ.bid TaqQ.ex]) %this is very slow
```

`csvwrite('test.csv',[TaqQ.time' ; TaqQ.bid'; TaqQ.ex']) % fast but don't know how to deal with it in MySql!?`

I also tried using fastinsert, but i was way to slow.

I also tried:

```
 connHandle = conn.Handle;
 stmt = connHandle.createStatement;
 for i= 1:2100000
 stmt.addBatch('INSERT INTO Quotes (time,bid,ex) VALUES (TaqQ.time(i),
 TaqQ.bid(i), TaqQ.ex(i))')
```

end
stmt.executeBatch;
stmt.close;
`

But i was also way to slow

can somebody help me??

Comment: How would you define *fast*? Also, how much memory do you have available on your machine? (the ourput of the command `memory` on Windows installations)

Comment: I have 8GB ram and running Mac osx yosemite. The things i have tried takes about 10 minutes. i would like it to take only about 30 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take a lot of RAM, but it will do things in memory, minimize the number of function calls, and will write everything at once, so it should be fast:

```
% Test struct
TaqQ = struct( ...
   'time', [1;2;3;4;5], ...
   'bid',  [110.1;120.1;130.1;140.1;150.1], ...
   'ex',   ['ABCD';'EFGH';'IJKL';'MNOP';'QRST'] ...
);

% Writing the file
NL = 10;           % ASCII new line
DQ = double('"');  % ASCII double quote

f = fopen('test.csv', 'wb');
fwrite(f, [ ...
   reshape(sprintf('% 10u,',   TaqQ.time), 11, []); ...  % 10 digits
   reshape(sprintf('% 10.3f,', TaqQ.bid),  11, []); ...  % 10 digits + point + sign 
          char(DQ*(ones(1,size(TaqQ.ex,1))));       ...  % open quotes
                               TaqQ.ex.';           ...  % already char
          char(DQ*(ones(1,size(TaqQ.ex,1))));       ...  % end quotes
          char(NL*(ones(1,size(TaqQ.ex,1))))        ...  % newlines
]);
fclose(f);
```

Actually I'm curious if it's fast, I could not test on huge data. Please let me know.

If you want to squeeze out all the spaces, then this is a (slower) variant:

```
% Preparing content
NL = 10;           % ASCII new line
DQ = double('"');  % ASCII double quote
bytes =  [ ...
   reshape(sprintf('% 10u,',   TaqQ.time), 11, []); ...  % 10 digits
   reshape(sprintf('% 10.3f,', TaqQ.bid),  11, []); ...  % 10 digits + point + sign 
          char(DQ*(ones(1,size(TaqQ.ex,1))));       ...  % open quotes
                               TaqQ.ex.';           ...  % already char
          char(DQ*(ones(1,size(TaqQ.ex,1))));       ...  % end quotes
          char(NL*(ones(1,size(TaqQ.ex,1))))        ...  % newlines
];

% Writing content without spaces
f = fopen('test.csv', 'wb');
fwrite(f,bytes(bytes~=' '));
fclose(f);
```

Comment: It is fast but It does not give the right answer. It write all on one line.

Comment: Some of the line  is446666677777777053334400012333074597703895069025214400304533079053604604517,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: No commas? that's odd... could you post on your question the first 5 records in each of your data?

Comment: I replaced TaqQ.time by TaqQ.time(1:15)

Comment: TaqQ.bid with TaqQ.bid(1:15)

Comment: TaqQ.ex with TaqQ.ex(1:15)

Comment: Just so i can se the output

Comment: 44 4  4  444444770700700777778...............770700700777970880800811888990000000000000000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,PPTPTTPTTPPPPTP

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. I'll correct the solution and come back

Comment: @SørenJ Now it should work. Still curious how many seconds it takes.

Comment: Please note that the strings are unquoted. What king of quotes to you want? I'll then add the code.

Comment: it print alot of spaces for the first path

Comment: @SørenJ Of course it plots a lot of spaces. Those spaces are used as padding, so we can take advantage of MATLAB's speed on matrix manipulations. Almost there with the quotes (I'll add double quotes).

Comment: i'm not sure yet. Can you make one with and one without :)

Comment: there are still unfilled spaceses

Comment: @SørenJ It's done. Still you didn't address my curiosity: how long it takes to run on your data. :-D

Comment: i'm running MacBook 2008

Comment: @SørenJ Thanks. Also, if you find that my reply answered your question/problem, please chose it as the answer.